# Outlook Macro / delete all other Categories of a mail after adding "Done" category

Tags: vba, outlook

I use multiple categories to track the progression of certain mails.

After completing the task, i mark associated mails with the "Done" category and would like to remove all other attached categories.

ty

Nothing much i dont really understand coding and didn`t find microsofts guides any helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Set the `MailItem.Categories` property to a `";"` separated list of categories. `"Done"` in your case.

Comment: Ok, sounds simple. 
The only question i have is, where do I set the property and how do i create such list?

Comment: When and how exactly do you need to do that?

Comment: there is no need for when.
How exactly? I do not know, i tried "Visual basic Editor" for outlook macros, but I have failed.

Comment: When as in "what message do you want to operate on? Th currently selected message? The message being displayed in an inspector? The message as soon as it is delivered to your inbox?

Comment: No no, i just want to combine the actions of deleting all categories and adding a "Done" cartegoy. 

I do organize my Mail-workflos in categories, so every mail has 2-5 categories, after i am done i delete all of them and add a "Done" category. 
I just want to automate the delete all other categories, action.

So to answer your question, i guess the currently selected one, since it is the one I add those categories to

Comment: You don't need to explicitly delete old categories - when you set `MailItem.Categories` property to `"Done"`, all old categories will be wiped out and you will have a single (new) category set.

Comment: Ok good to know, but still with normal Outlook, categories are added to the already existing bunch. 
So I need to configure it in a way, that when adding the "Done" category, the MailItem.Categories will be changed from Standard to "Done". 

I am not a big programmer, I do not know which object i need to edit. The action itself will be a simple IF statement, which reacts to the user input of applying a category to the selected mail.

Comment: When you set categories **programmatically**, you affect **all** categories. I still do not understand what you are trying to do. From my earlier comment "When as in "what message do you want to operate on? Th currently selected message? The message being displayed in an inspector? The message as soon as it is delivered to your inbox?"